# How to pass the long string in URL?

Tags: android

I want to pass the keyword (**="mexico city"**) keyword in this url http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+**keyword** +"&sensor=false" without trimming the empty spaces. how to insert it.

Comment: `usrStringObject = usrSTringObject.replaceAll(" ","%20");`

Comment: @Frankenstein Which will "work just fine" until the address contains a `&`... (or numerous other characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android or Java in general, you may want to use the [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

```java
String keywordEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(keyword, "UTF-8");
String urlEncoded = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                    + keywordEncoded
                    + "&sensor=false";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace spaces with %20 its hex equivalent of space which is parsed by http server as space

Comment: Which will "work just fine" until the address contains a `&`... (or numerous other characters)

Answer (score 0):

The you need to replace the space with %20.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mexico%20citysensor=false

Comment: Which will "work just fine" until the address contains a `&`... (or numerous other characters)

Comment: That is correct, then they need to be escaped with their hex equivalent too.

Comment: Yes, which is why I cannot up-vote this answer. It does solve this particular case, but not the issue in general.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the correct URL by replacing the empty string with `%20`

`usrStringObject = usrSTringObject.replaceAll(" ","%20");`

Comment: Which will "work just fine" until the address contains a `&`... (or numerous other characters)

Comment: yes right..for that need to convert each special charater to its known representation in HTML format..